# Popen Launch Window On Screen

Tags: python

I currently have the below code which launches a bat file, waits a few seconds, and then enters a command into the bat window. This currently is working.

```
    # find bat file to open (named echo_test.bat)
    os.chdir(target_dir)
    target = [x for x in os.listdir('.') if 'echo_test' in x][0]
    print target
    # open file, wait, and write "test" to it
    p = Popen('{}'.format(target), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    time.sleep(2)
    p.stdin.write('test')
    time.sleep(4)
    sys.exit(0)
```

How can I have the initial bat file that I open launch interactively on the screen? I've tried passing `/k` to it but it's not doing anything. I seem to be missing something.

Comment: Echo_test is a bat file. It simply checks to see what you input to it. If you input “test” it launches another program. Otherwise it does nothing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I’m wondering how I can have the bat file launch on the screen. I have the bat file launching notepad when I input “test”. Notepad launches on the screen but the bat file remains in the background.

Comment: when starting another console, standard input isn't redirected anymore. It's a bit like running notepad and hoping to write a string in it by redirecting input...

Comment: So how can I open the bat file, keep it open, and send a command to it?

Comment: I need to launch the bat file on the screen and send a command to it. That’s it.

Comment: but you're stating that your example works. So it doesn't work?

Comment: My example doesn’t show the bat file on the screen. It opens it in the background and passes a command to it

Comment: "show the .bat" on the screen? you mean in a new window then. If so, no can do....

Comment: I see. What’s the closest thing possible?

Comment: maybe write to a temporary file using python, pass the file as a parameter of your .bat file, and read from the file. But you cannot really interact in that case, since the output file needs to be closed before the .Bat reads it.